# How would you check with restFB that a random chain of digits is a valid Facebook ID?

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I was wondering if there's a single access token for all Facebook users. Beside, how would you check with restFB that a random chain of digits is a valid Facebook ID?

Comment: By "single access token for all Facebook users", do you mean an app access token? Depending on what kind of requests you're making, you could fetch data using an app access token. You can also use the app access token to create a client, then request an ID to determine if it's a valid ID. `facebookClient.fetchObject(fbid, User.class);` should return a User object if it's a valid ID.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `facebookClient.fetchObject(<id>, JsonObject.class)`. So you get a `JsonObject`.

A random chain of digits can be mapped to a Post, Application, Comment, User and so on.